# How to deploy MIDlet application use eclipse?

Tags: java, android, blackberry, java-me, midlet

I am using EclipseME to write MIDlet application.

I have deployed by right click on `Project->J2ME->Create Package`.

After that, I copied Jad and Jar files in Deploy folder to My phone.

For BlackBerry: When I run Jad file, it is installed successful. And run ok.

For Android: When I run jar file, it popup message "open file failed".

Please tell me how to deploy MIDlet app by using Eclipse for all cell phone that can run it.

Answer (score 2):

Android phones can't runt J2ME.

Answer (score 2):

Directly you can't run Java ME application on android. But You can use some alternative ways like [App runner](http://www.netmite.com/android/) or [J2ab.](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/j2ab)

Answer (score 0):

For Android you should develop an application using android sdk. Better you read the android documentation. Search android in google. It will help you.